# Remove reactions to our own messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I would like my bot to remove reactions to our own messages

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944 or 469197781308014593:
        if payload.emoji.name == "dev":
            if payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944:
                channel = client.get_channel(614467771866021944)
            if payload.channel_id == 469197781308014593:
                channel = client.get_channel(469197781308014593)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            emoji = get(channel.guild.emojis, name=payload.emoji.name)
            reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
            async for user in reaction.users():
                if user == message.author:
                    # delete the reaction
```

Comment: `payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944 or 469197781308014593` should be `payload.channel_id in (614467771866021944, 469197781308014593)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944 or 469197781308014593:
```

this line will be always evaluated as True, because `469197781308014593` is always True, like said in comment, you should use the `in` keyword in these case.

```
        if payload.channel_id == 614467771866021944:
            channel = client.get_channel(614467771866021944)
        if payload.channel_id == 469197781308014593:
            channel = client.get_channel(469197781308014593)
```

can be shorted to

```
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
```

---

Final code :

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id in [614467771866021944, 469197781308014593]:
        if payload.emoji.name == "dev":
            channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            emoji = get(channel.guild.emojis, name=payload.emoji.name)
            reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
            async for user in reaction.users():
                if user == message.author:
                    await reaction.remove(user)
```